# how to determine late or go home in one function in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two conditions of time :

first: 07:30

second: 16:40

The problem is I want to check two values in that conditions. I want to check if that value (time) is late arrival or leave early on a workday of the company.

If the first value is 07:50 that means late and the second value is 16:10 that means go home early. I want to handle that values in one function.

please help.
that's function had I already make before

this is my simple code :

```
foreach ($arr_att_log as $key => $value) {
                            if (nBetween($value, $ending_in, $begin_in)) {
                                $arr_validIn[$key]  = $value;
                            }elseif (nBetween($value, $ending_break, $begin_break)) {
                                $arr_validBreak[$key] = $value;
                            }elseif (nBetween($value, $ending_out, $begin_out)) {
                                $arr_validOut[$key] = $value;
                            }
                        }
```

and here my function :

```
function nBetween($varToCheck, $high, $low) {
        if($varToCheck < $low) return false;
        if($varToCheck > $high) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you put a sample code in the question itself ?

Comment: @AdeKurniawan you can edit the question and place the code in as a codeblock.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add the code rather than leaving it in comments.

Comment: If you than put it as solution as answer please.

Comment: that's my simple code and does not work, please help